# Pandas if statement based on matching two different column values

Tags: python, pandas

How would I do this: I want to add a new column that tells me if for the same id they have both 'blue' and 'green' associated with it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'b1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    'value' : ['blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
})
```

So what it should look like is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id' : ['a1', 'a1', 'b1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    'value' : ['blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']
    'both' : [True, True, True, True, False]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['both'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda x: set(x).issuperset({'blue', 'green'}))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  value   both
0  a1   blue   True
1  a1  green   True
2  b1  green   True
3  b1   blue   True
4  c1   blue  False
```

Comment: What happens if the `value` column's values are unknown?

Comment: @U10-Forward True. I've edited to check if `issuperset`. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Still, you're using `blue` and `green` which could be other colors

Comment: @U10-Forward For that, I'm unsure if OP wants to check which `id` has all unique elements or just some random elements (coincided with the unique this time). Now that I think about it, with given number of assumptions, I might've answer bit early :P

Comment: Who knows actually :-) my answer does it programmatically you do it manually see what the OP want :P

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby`:

```
df['both'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform('unique').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(df['value'].unique()).isin(x))[1]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   id  value   both
0  a1   blue   True
1  a1  green   True
2  b1  green   True
3  b1   blue   True
4  c1   blue  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('id')['value'].unique().apply(lambda x: ('blue' in x) and ('green' in x)).reset_index().rename(columns={'value': 'both'}), on='id', how='left')
```

and the output would be:

```
    id  value   both
0   a1  blue    True
1   a1  green   True
2   b1  green   True
3   b1  blue    True
4   c1  blue    False
```